# Netbeans "Add-JAR" causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, netbeans, plugins, jar, null

I am trying to attach a jar library toolkit to one of my netbeans projects. However, when I go to File > Project Properties > Libraries > Add Wrapped Jar the import succeeds but running the plugin causes a NullPointerException. I suspect this has something to do with the path but I don't understand how to manipulate the path or why there is even a null pointer.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.gephi.desktop.recentfiles.RecentFiles.getMenuPresenter(RecentFiles.java:88)
    at org.openide.awt.DynaMenuModel.loadSubmenu(DynaMenuModel.java:100)
    at org.openide.awt.MenuBar$LazyMenu$MenuFolder.createInstance(MenuBar.java:831)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.defaultProcessObjectsFinal(FolderInstance.java:885)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$1R.run(FolderInstance.java:730)
    at org.openide.util.Task.run(Task.java:253)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.openide.loaders.AWTTask.run(AWTTask.java:79)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.loaders.AWTTask$Processor.run(AWTTask.java:171)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:158)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 0):

A NPE should not happen. So please file an issue at https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/